# error explanation - 'statInter' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a simple timer in Python and am aiming to build the user interface using classes. I would like to use the classes to initialise user interface. Then in the main text of the body, I would like to add attributes using the .grid and .configure methods. But when I try to do this, the error: 'statInter' object has no attribute 'tk' appears.

I am a beginner in programming, but if I understand the error correctly the it results because the .grid and other Button methods are not inherited by my statInter (i.e. static interface) class. Is this correct? How do I solve this error? I trued inheriting the properties of Button class and even Tk class, but in the later case I get an infinite loop i.e. maximum recursion depth exceeded.

Thanks for your help

```
#This is a simple timer version

from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title('Tea timer')
window.minsize(300,100)
window.resizable(0,0)

class statInter(Button,Entry):

    def __init__(self, posx, posy):
        self.posx = posx  # So the variables inside the class are defined broadly
        self.posy = posy

    def button(self):
        Button(window).grid(row=self.posx, column=self.posy)

    def field(self):
        Entry(window, width=5)

sth = statInter(1,2)
sth.grid(row=1, column = 2)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your derived `StatInter` class ([CamelCasing](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) the class name as suggested in [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) doesn't initialize its base classes, which generally *doesn't* happen implicitly in Python (as it does in say, C++).

In order to do that from within the `StatInter.__init__()` method, you're going to need to know the `parent` widget that will contain it (all widgets except the top level window are contained in a hierarchy) — so an extra argument needs to be passed to the derived class's constructor so it can be passed on to each of the base class constructors.

You haven't encountered another problem yet, but likely will soon. To avoid it, you're also going to have explicitly pass `self` when explicitly calling the base class methods in `button()` and `field()`.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title('Tea timer')
window.minsize(300,100)
window.resizable(0,0)

class StatInter(Button, Entry):

    def __init__(self, parent, posx, posy):  # Added parent argument
        Button.__init__(self, parent)  # Explicit call to base class
        Entry.__init__(self, parent)  # Explicit call to base class
        self.posx = posx  # So the variables inside the class are defined broadly
        self.posy = posy

    def button(self):
        Button.grid(self, row=self.posx, column=self.posy)  # Add self

    def field(self):
        Entry.config(self, width=5)  # Add self

sth = StatInter(window, 1, 2)  # Add parent argument to call
sth.grid(row=1, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a good answer, though I suspect the OP is _either_ wanting to inherit from `Button` and `Entry`, _or_ use composition to create a `Button` and `Entry`, but not both.

Comment: @Bryan: Thanks. You're right about there being an "is-a" vs "has-a" issue, of course. I was attempting to answer well enough to solve the immediate problem so the OP could continue their development — as well as point out some potential future pitfalls when doing multiple inheritance in Python, which is what I think probably was what they were trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get this error is because you never invoke either of the constructors from the classes you're inheriting from (either `Button` or `Entry`).

If you change your `__init__` to be:

```
def __init__(self, posx, posy):
    Button.__init__(self)
    self.posx = posx  # So the variables inside the class are defined broadly
    self.posy = posy
```

Then you won't get the error you were having previously, and a little window pops up. In the new `__init__`, we explicitly invoke `Button`'s constructor.

Unlike Java and some other languages, the `super` constructor is NOT invoked by default. I assume that each class inheriting from other `tkinter` classes must have a `tk` field. By invoking the parent constructor of your choice, this field will be created. If you don't invoke a parent constructor, though, then this will not be an established field, and you'll get the error you have described ('statInter' object has no attribute 'tk').

HTH!